# Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib error on OS X 10.7

Tags: macos, ncurses

I'm trying to update the `ncurses-5.4` to `ncurses-5.9` on Mac OS X 10.7.

I've built `ncurses-5.9`

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ncurses-5.9 --with-shared
```

To do the update:

```
sudo mv /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib_BACKUP
sudo ln -s =/usr/local/ncurses-5.9/lib/libncurses.5.dylib /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
```

But after I do it, I get this sort of errors:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm
  Reason: Incompatible library version: iTerm requires version 5.4.0 or later,
but libncurses.5.4.dylib provides version 5.0.0
```

How to update it to `ncurses-5.9`? Thank you.

Comment: More than one thing to do, but starting by looking at Apple's [configuration](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-36/) is a start.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Is it to say that I should use Xcode to produce the `.dylib` ? I've used the Autoconf & Automake build system to build the binary and it produced  only the`x86_64` binary, i.e. no `universal binary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Apple's [configuration](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-36/).  The [`config.status`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/ncurses/ncurses-36/generated.autoconf_configure/config.status.auto.html) file happens to tell you what configure-options were used:

```
  with options \"--prefix=/usr --disable-dependency-tracking --disable-mixed-case --with-shared --without-normal --without-debug --enable-termcap --enable-widec --with-abi-version=5.4 --without-cxx-binding --without-cxx --mandir=/usr/share/man 'CFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -g -Os -pipe -isysroot /' 'CXXFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc -g -Os -pipe ' 'LDFLAGS=-arch i386 -arch x86_64 -arch ppc            '\"
```

You should read the [`INSTALL`](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/master/INSTALL) description for each option, to understand what's done, but the pertinent one for your question is this:

```
--with-abi-version=5.4
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added just the `--with-abi-version=5.4` option and the `CFLAGS` , `CXXFLAGS`  and the `LDFLAGS` and did the same  `ln` symbolic linking and it did work.